# KeyCloak: Read user's Administrative units from Azure AD IdP

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, keycloak

Is it possible to read user’s administrative units from Azure AD (oidc Identity provider) and store as attribute?

End goal is for JWT to include information about user's Administrative units and/or Organization units (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

In theory: Azure ID needs to add user’s administrative units into OIDC claim. Then configure Keycloak Identity Provider mappers and map that claim into Keycloak entity (user attribute/role/...). Then Keycloak clients can use it in their own mappers configuration.